# Using RabbitMQ RPC doesn't fail when there is no consumer. Is this the expected behaviour?

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I'm implementing two services: **A** and **B**. I'm trying to implement a syncronous communication (Remote Procedure Call, or RPC) between A and B.

## Scenario

Very simple. **A** needs a information from **B**, so **A** send a message and wait for a reply from **B**. **A** can't continue without this information

## The question

I'm using the method `rabbitTemplate.convertSendAndReceive` from Spring RabbitMQ. This works as expected if the **B** is running. My code is very similar from [this link](https://reflectoring.io/event-messaging-with-spring-boot-and-rabbitmq/).

If **B** is not running, **A** waits for a little time (few seconds) and receive as reply a `null`. In this case, I was expectating some exception saying that there is no consumer available.

The [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#reply-timeout) says:

> By default, the send and receive methods will timeout after 5 seconds
>   and return null. This can be modified by setting the replyTimeout
>   property. Starting with version 1.5, if you set the mandatory property
>   to true (or the mandatory-expression evaluates to true for a
>   particular message), if the message cannot be delivered to a queue an
>   AmqpMessageReturnedException will be thrown. This exception has
>   returnedMessage, replyCode, replyText properties, as well as the
>   exchange and routingKey used for the send.

I tried to set:

```
rabbitTemplate.setMandatory(true);
```

But any exception is throwed. I think because the queue is still alive in RabbitMQ, because there is some messages sent from A when B are out and they are waiting for to processed by **B**.

So, the `null` return is how I know that there is no consumer?

Another problem in this case: the message sent from **A** will be waiting in the queue until **B** consumes. But as I'm implementing a syncronous communication, this behaviour not make any sense if **B** is not running, because when **B** starts again it will consume and process without return the information to **A**. This will be a "lost" processing. Is this normal with RabbitMQ RPC communication?

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.9 and the dependency `spring-cloud-starter-stream-rabbit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mandatory has nothing to with consumers; it's to ensure the message was delivered to a queue.

Yes, getting `null` is an indication that the operation timed out (5 seconds by default).

You can configure the queue with a time to live (ttl) so stale messages will be removed from the queue if they are not processed within that time.

Comment: Thanks (again) Garry :D